# control with image, title and hyperlinks like in VS

Tags: wpf

I am completely new to wpf and the question is this.
Is there available xaml for the control like on attached image?

[image]

As you can see, when we click on a control the image on the left becomes larger and all the text slides to the left.  Or how could I create similar control?

Comment: what you try? just start to, create a usercontrol, that have look like there, then add animation and ...

Comment: Well, ArsenMkrt, I have a book that is about 750 pages large and I can go ahead and read it for a couple month.  But then what would I need this forum?  Do you have ideas how this control is done?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish that is a Storyboard.

Open Expression-Blend, build a Control. Hide all Elements you dont see first so its small. Create a new Storyboard, make a Keyframe and change the Properties of the elements you then want to change, create a new Keyframe.

Its like an Animation now. You can now start the Storyboard any time, on any event to expand your control.

If you dont know how to use Expression Blend and the Storyboard, there are some fine Tutorials and Videos.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for lead.  Is Expression Blend free?  will I need additional assemblies for the installation on the user target machine?

Comment: No, Expression Blend for Windows Phone is free. And you dont need any additional Assemblies. It generates native XAML. The Product is from Microsoft itself.